# How to do revision management for Google Drive custom objects?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-revisions

I understand you can manage revisions for recognized file types like Google Doc, Spreadsheet, etc. How about custom objects?

By custom objects, I mean the Book example in this link.
https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/build-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Realtime API does not support managing revisions right now. You can use the import/export API to get a snapshot of the document at a particular revision, and do your own revision management, but its not currently handled in a generalized way like for docs, spreadsheets, etc.